# merging two lists into a dictionary with exceptions challenge

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to merge two lists into a dictionary while excluding the integers from the first list and the strings from the second list.

```py
list1 = ["A","B","C","D","E" ,"F", 1 ,"G", 3 ,"H","I","J","K","L"]
list2 = [20 ,27 , "Arm","Leg", 13 , 24 ,"Head", 75 , 64 , 71 ,"Ankle", 82 , 45 , 23]
```

I tried using the code below:

```py
dictchallenge ={[x for x in list1 if  isinstance(x, str)][i]: [x for x in list2 if isinstance(x, int)][i] for i in range(len([x for x in list1 if  isinstance(x, int)]))}
print(dictchallenge)
```

The output of the code is:

```
{'A': 20, 'B': 27}
```

The code is only merging the first two strings from the keys list with first two integers from the value list, I need to merge all the keys in the first list with all the values in the second list like this:

```py
{'A': 20, 'B': 27, 'E': 13, 'F': 24, 'G': 75, 'H': 71, 'J': 82, 'K': 45, 'L': 23 }
```

If anyone can help me with that, thank you.

Comment: try not to do everything in one line, you are just hurting yourself.

Comment: Check what `len([x for x in list1 if  isinstance(x, int)])` produces and you'll get the issue.  And please don't try to save lines of code - you are hurting readability and performance by doing so

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I wrote it in on one line because the professor give us a challenge to write the shortest program to do it. I tried len([x for x in list1 if isinstance(x, str)])          and I got an erorr list out of index

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is first get the indexes from both lists that you don't need:

```
>>> indexes = [i for i in range(len(list1)) if not isinstance(list1[i], str)]
>>> indexes += [i for i in range(len(list2)) if not isinstance(list2[i], int)]
```

Then you get rid of the elements you don't need:

```
>>> clean_list1 = [list1[i] for i in range(len(list1)) if i not in indexes]
>>> clean_list2 = [list2[i] for i in range(len(list2)) if i not in indexes]
```

And finally you can zip both lists:

```
>>> dict(zip(clean_list1, clean_list2))
{'A': 20, 'B': 27, 'E': 13, 'F': 24, 'G': 75, 'H': 71, 'J': 82, 'K': 45, 'L': 23}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice, I think the easiest way to do it is using zip like you did, the only problem is the professor in college give as a challenge to write the shortest program to do it without using zip.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 1, "G", 3, "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
    list2 = [20, 27, "Arm", "Leg", 13, 24, "Head", 75, 64, 71, "Ankle", 82, 45, 23]
    d={}
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            if str(j).isdigit()==True and list1.index(i)==list2.index(j):
                d[i]=j
    
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way using one for loop and check if `list1` has key as *string*
and `list2` has value as an *int*, if So add it to a *dict* `output` and increment `i` and `j`.

```py
list1 = ["A","B","C","D","E" ,"F", 1 ,"G", 3 ,"H","I","J","K","L"]
list2 = [20 ,27 , "Arm","Leg", 13 , 24 ,"Head", 75 , 64 , 71 ,"Ankle", 82 , 45 , 23]

i=0
j=0
output = {}
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if isinstance(list1[i] , str):
        if isinstance(list2[i] , int):
            output[list1[i]] = list2[i]
            j+=1
        i+=1
print(output)
```

*output:*

```
{'A': 20, 'B': 27, 'E': 13, 'F': 24, 'G': 75,
 'H': 71, 'J': 82, 'K': 45, 'L': 23}
```